# Windows authentication fails and needs to be reset

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-authentication

I have an existing IIS web app with windows authentication enabled. When I run this command, to set bindings, Windows authentication fails and I have to manually disable and re-enable windows authentication for it to work.

```
import-module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Test\My" -name bindings -value (@{protocol="https";bindingInformation="*:443:my.test.com";sslFlags=1},@{protocol="net.tcp";bindingInformation="808:my.test.com"})
```

I have tried setting windows authentication with powershell but had no effect.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/WindowsAuthentication -name enabled -value true -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\TestMy"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue may be that we haven’t bound a certificate to the specific port yet.
After specifying an Https binding, please bind a certificate to that port.

> Netsh http add sslcert ipport=1.1.1.1:443
> certhash=0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011121314
> appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert
This is commonly finished by the IIS. Without this procedure, the website could work improperly over https binding. You could try to set up an HTTP binding on the website in order to rule this point out.
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.